# How to replace cart items programmatically?

Tags: cart, event-observer, quote

I tried two different approaches for this, but both failing at different point.

1. By calling `$cart->truncate()->save()` and then `$cart->addProduct($product, $qty)`. But instead of replacing the whole cart with new items, overlapping items (with or without the same quantity) will be deleted anyways.
2. I also tried `$quote->removeAllItems()->collectTotals()->save()` and then `$cart->addProduct($product, $qty)`, but when the quantity of an overlapping item is collectively larger than stock level, it will prompt a false **out of stock** error message.

**More on 2**

I have dived into the code which checks stock level, which is `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty()`.

Every time I test with code in 2), a total of four times it checked and in the 3rd time the `$qtyForCheck`  of that particular overlapping item is summed up with quantities before *AND* after `removeAllItems()`, effectively generating a false error prompt.

Comment: 1) isn't working for you as you need to call it as follows: `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();`

Comment: @moose but `$cart->truncate()` is actually a wrapper to `$quote->removeAllItems()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not re-declare cart & start over like this?

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session->getQuote()->delete();
$session->clear();

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->setQuote($session->getQuote());

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> load($product_id);
if ($product) {
    if ($product -> isSaleable()) {
        $cart -> addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    }
}

// $session->setCartWasUpdated(true); // Not really necessary - Vicary
$cart->save();
```

Comment: AFAIK the Cart model is just a wrapper to the Quote model, the Quote id is stored in `checkout/session` and this should end up working on the same quote. One still need to clear quote items before calling `$cart->addProduct()`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the delete call on the current quote model. P.S. The reason 1) may not be working for you is because you're not calling the `->setCartWasUpdated(true);` function.

Comment: Tried to delete the quote with no luck. The latter created cart still loads the same quote which is going to be deleted.

Comment: Found the solution, after quote deletion one must call `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear()` before the cart can generate a new quote. Please add that to your answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Ah, good find. Have approved your edit.

Comment: perfect answer +1!!!